infinte loop when transforming django into exe file
I want to execute " runserver" command and "run_file_watcher" which is custom command at the same time each one on a sperate thread , it works fine , but when transforming it into exe file with Pyinstaller it go for infinite loop
this is the code for multithreading


# run_both.py
import os
from threading import Thread
import subprocess
import sys
import django

# Set Django settings module explicitly
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')
django.setup()

def run_django_server():
    print("Starting Django server...")
    subprocess.run([sys.executable, 'manage.py', 'runserver'])
    print("Django server finished.")

def run_custom_command():
    print("Running custom command...")
    subprocess.run([sys.executable, 'manage.py', 'run_file_watcher'])
    print("Custom command finished.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create threads
    thread1 = Thread(target=run_django_server)
    thread2 = Thread(target=run_custom_command)
    thread1.start() # returns immediately
    thread2.start() # returns immediately


sys.executable doesn't mean the same thing during runtime when your executable was bundled with pyinstaller.

i didn't know that, but what can replace it with to prevent the infinite loop ?

Instead of using threading, you can use multiprocessing module bc it works better with pyinstaller.

i tried and , i got same result

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
